# PHP / MySQL count (*) and using var in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to count all rows of a dataset and would like to print the number later as part of a small statistic.

But I'm not sure, where my error might be. The html returns (echo) works well if I only display a text, but it won't show the amount of rows.

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("inc/config.inc.php");
require_once("inc/functions.inc.php");

$user = check_user();

include("templates/header.inc.php");

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM gamesnw");
$nw = $statement->fetch();

?>
```

html:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <h1><?php echo htmlentities($nw); ?><h1>
  <h3>Nachwuchsspiele</h3>
   <p>Anzahl in der Datenbank erfasste Nachwuchsspiele.</p>
</div>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not execute your prepared statement. What you have to do is add this after your prepared statement: `$statement->execute()`. Hope I helped :)

Comment: Works, but now the output of the echo is "Array". But what I want is the amount of rows as a integer. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Then you should use `print_r` for outputting the array . `echo` only works on strings not arrays. Or what you could is `echo $nw[0];`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that.
The output is now "Array ( [count(id)] => 14 [0] => 14 )". Any idea how I can display only "14"?

Comment: Ok then use `echo $nw[0]` to display the first element and `echo $nw[1]` to display the second element or even better, you could iterate it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
"SELECT count(*) FROM gamesnw"
```

to

```
"SELECT count(*) AS cntt FROM gamesnw"
```

Comment: Did not solve the problem. Also no return at the html part.